# Is there a way to transfer all attributes from one element to another element?

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing an AJAX site and in order to execute my imported scripts I must create new identical scripts in order for the DOM to run them. I was wondering if there is a simple built in method or another easy way to copy all the attributes of one script tag to another one without having to transfer them all individually.

Basically what I am looking for is this:

In the HTML:

```
<script id = "myscript" src = "somefile.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
```

In the JS:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.innerHTML = document.getElementById("myscript").innerHTML;
script.attributes = document.getElementById("myscript").attributesList;
```

How I am currently getting by is assigning each attribute individually to the new script object, and I think it's a bit tedious.

Comment: Yep, you can use [element.attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes).

Comment: To be honest, it was lazy of me to ask this question. I had just spent about 8 hours staring at my computer screen trying to get the loaded scripts to run, and I was just looking for an easy fix. @Spencer, that actually works well.

Answer (score 6):

I eventually decided to just go with a loop to populate the attributes list on the new script element:

```
for (index = old_script.attributes.length - 1; index > -1; -- index) {

  attribute = old_script.attributes[index];
  new_script.setAttribute(attribute.name, attribute.value);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use node#attributes

```js
var $oldScript = $("oldScript");
var $newScript = $("newScript");

var attributes = $oldScript.prop("attributes");

// loop through oldScript attributes and apply them on new script
$.each(attributes, function() {
    $newScript.attr(this.name, this.value);
});
```

Comment: A couple of tips: 1) if you're going to use Stack Snippets, please click the "Run code snippet" button to ensure that the code actually runs. 2) If the OP does not mention jQuery in the question or tags, it's best to call out that you are using jQuery in your answer.